# Find a closed form for this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

For some value of $k$, $a_j=0$ for all $j\leq k$. Then, for $n\geq 1$,

$$a_{n+k}=\frac{n}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k}a_i$$

What is a closed form for $a_k$?

I found that $$a_{n+k}=\frac{n}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k}a_{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k-1}a_i$$
so that
$$\frac{n+k+1}{n+k}a_{n+k}=\frac{n}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k-1}a_i$$
and
$$a_{n+k}=\frac{n}{n+k+1}-\frac{1}{n+k+1}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k-1}a_i$$
But I don't know where to go from here. I calculated the first few terms, but I couldn't find a pattern. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\cases{
(n+k)a_{n+k}=n-\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k}a_i\\
(n+k-1)a_{n+k-1}=n-1-\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+k-1}a_i
}
$$

after subtraction

$$
(n+k)a_{n+k}-(n+k-1)a_{n+k-1} = 1-a_{n+k}\Rightarrow (n+k+1)a_{n+k}-(n+k-1)a_{n+k-1} =1
$$

now making $m = n+k$ we have

$$
(m+1)a_m-(m-1)a_{m-1}=1 \Rightarrow a_m = \frac{c_0}{m(m+1)}+\frac 12
$$

or

$$
a_{n+k} = \frac{c_0}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}+\frac 12
$$

Comment: Thank you! What is $c_0$?

Comment: This constant is to be defined according to the initial conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry—I just realized there was a small typo in my statement of the problem ($\frac{k}{n+k}$ should have been $\frac{n}{n+k}$). I've updated the question. Your answer more or less translates, right?

Comment: The answer was modified accordingly.